# Using the xr package in LyX (for cross-referencing an external LyX document)

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, external-files

**Question**: What steps are required to use the `xr` package in LyX in order to reference items in other, independent LyX documents?

**Steps already taken**:

1. The `tools` package (that contains the `xr` package) has been installed in MikTeX.
2. The `xr` package has been used in the referencing document (by adding `\usepackage{xr}` to the referencing document's preamble).
3. A pointer to the referenced document has been set in the referencing document (by adding `\externaldocument{referenced.lyx}` to the referencing document's preamble).
4. A label in the referenced document has been cross-referenced in the the referencing document using the `\ref` tag.

**Observed (undesired) behavior**: The reference appears as "BROKEN" in the LyX editor. The PDF output shows "??" where the reference number is expected.

**Relevant links**:

1. [A thread on a LyX usegroup](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/71328)
2. [Another thread on a LyX usegroup](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/39160)

**Software used**: LyX + MiKTeX + BibTeX on Windows 7

**My level of Lyx/LaTeX proficiency**: Beginner+

Comment: Any updates to this in the last 10 years?

Answer (score 7):

I have been trying to get `xr` and `xcite` working for past couple days in LyX and this post and the links it cites were about all I could find as references.  Since the current answer doesn't fully explain what is going on in LyX, I'll give what works for me for using `xr` (or `xcite`) with LyX:

1. Put

   ```
   \usepackage{xr}
   \externaldocument{referenced}
   ```

   into the LaTeX preamble in Document->Settings of the referencing document (I will call it `referencing.lyx`).
2. Build the referenced document to obtain `referenced.aux`.

   You can either do File->Export to export `referenced.tex` and run `latex` on it to generate `referenced.aux` or you build the document normally in LyX with the View command.  If you use the View command, you will need to find LyX's temporary directory where it ran latex.  This directory should be a subdirectory of the `Temporary directory` listed under the Paths section of LyX's Preferences.  The LyX subdirectories (there might be more than one depending on how many document you have opened and rendered during the session) will have names starting with `lyx_tmpdir` and will contain subdirectories with names beginning with `lyx_tmpbuf`.  One of these `lyx_tmpbuf` directories should contain `referenced.aux` (if you start a new LyX session and View `referenced.lyx`, it should be easy to find since there shouldn't be a lot of extra LyX directories).  (Itai, LyX's temporary directory is usually located in a system temporary directory that does not show up in typical file searches, so that might be why you could not find any `.aux` files).
3. Once you have `referenced.aux`, just save it in the same directory as `referencing.lyx` and LyX should find it when it renders `referencing.pdf`.

Other usage notes:

- LyX does not have native support for `xr` or `xcite`.  Initially, the labels in `referenced.lyx` will not appear as options in the cross-reference dialog in LyX.  To reference items from `referenced.lyx` such as `referenced_label1`, you can either do "Insert->TeX Code" and put `\ref{referenced_label1}` in by hand, or you can keep `referenced.lyx` open, right-click on the label you want to reference and choose "Copy as reference", and then paste into `referencing.lyx` at the point where you want to make the reference.
- Because LyX does not have support for `xr`, pasted labels will show up in LyX with a `BROKEN:` prefixed in front of the label.  However, they should still be rendered properly in the pdf that is produced.  The `BROKEN:` prefix just means that LyX can't find that label defined within `referencing.lyx`. One way to get around this is to put `referencing.lyx` as a child document (Insert -> File -> Child Document) within a LyX note. Then its labels will show in the cross-reference dialog in LyX, but because the inclusion is within a LyX note, it won't get rendered in the .pdf.
- Pasted labels will appear in LyX's cross-reference dialog (as `BROKEN:` references).  Don't try to reference them from there though because you end up with a reference to a reference.
- With `xcite`, if you have a separate `.bib` file for `referenced.lyx` (call it `referenced.bib`), you can add `referenced.bib` to `referencing.lyx`'s bibliography and cite the items normally (rather than copying and pasting references out of `referenced.lyx`).  Then, when you want to render the `referencing.pdf`, remove `referenced.bib` from the bibliography.  This should break all of the citations within `referencing.lyx` but they should still be found by `xcite`.
- While searching for how to use `xr` with LyX, I saw references to a combo document option in LyX that would allow it to use the same temporary directory for two LyX files (in which case `referenced.aux` file could be made available to `referencing.lyx` without having to put it in the working directory as described above).  As far as I can tell, this feature was removed before LyX 2.0 and is not an option any more.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation of `xr` tells you to write

```
\externaldocument{referenced}
```

*without* an extension, as it needs to look at `referenced.aux` rather than `referenced.tex` (or a `.lyx` file). Clearly, the `.aux` file resulting from compilation of `referenced.tex` must be around in order to be consulted (in the same folder as the main document, or in some other place where LaTeX can find it).

Comment: Thanks. How can i produce an ".aux" file via Lyx?

Comment: @Itai I don't really know how LyX works, but I suppose that it runs LaTeX on the main document at some stage and this *will* produce an `.aux` file.

Comment: I've carried out a system-wide search for ".aux" files to no avail. Eventually, i've managed to generate an ".aux" by exporting the Lyx document to raw LaTeX and then compiling the latter in MiKTeX. Unfortunately, even now that the ".aux" file is available (in the same folder as both the referencing and the referenced files), the original error persists.

Comment: @Itai Sorry, I know nothing about the internal workings of LyX to be able to help more than this. Within a normal LaTeX run, `xr` tells LaTeX to look for the external `.aux` file where to read the external references, just like it looks in the usual `.aux` file produced during the previous run to resolve cross references. How LyX does this is unknown to me.

Comment: Is this still the state of the art?

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor Sorry, I still know nothing about LyX.